# maple cant calculate my function

Tags: math, maple

i must sorry for my bad english at start.
Im trying to do some math in maple.

My function

```
func(x) = x*e^(-x)-0.06064
```

i try to calculate
     f(0.05) * f(0.06) < 0

```
bn:= 0
mn := 0.06   
an := 0.05    
if (evalf( subs( x = mn, func ) )*evalf( subs( x = an, func ) )) < 0 then bn := mn;
```

but maple say:

> cannot determine if this expression is true or false:
>   (0.6000000000e-1/e^0.64692635994760e-1-0.6064e-1)*(0.5e-1/e^0.64692635994760e-1-0.6064e-1)
>   < 0

can i do something to calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

You main difficulty is that in Maple Notation powering by the base of the natural logarithm is done like,

```
exp( -x )
```

and not like,

```
e^( -x )
```

Notice the presence of the name `e` in the error message you received. In Maple the name `e` has no special meaning in 1D Maple Notation input.

Presumably you just stuck those calls to `evalf` in because you were trying to resolve your issue with `e`. In your example the floats have enough contagion to make the `evalf` calls unnecessary.

You might also be interested in these two variants to obtain an actual float from your formula. I leave out the unnecessary `evalf` calls here.

Here is `func` defined as an expression.

```
restart:
func := x*exp(-x) - 0.06064:
bn:= 0: mn := 0.06: an := 0.0:
eval( func, x=mn ) * eval( func, x=an );

                           0.0002506935207
```

And here is `func` defined as an operator.

```
restart:
func := x -> x*exp(-x)-0.06064:
bn:= 0: mn := 0.06: an := 0.0:
func( mn ) * func( an );

                           0.0002506935207
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your parenthesis are off a bit.  Try this:

```
if (evalf( subs( x = mn, func ) )*evalf( subs( x = an, func ) ) < 0) then bn := mn;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but still same problem